# Storing MySQL query result into a PHP array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

Looking at all the questions are using the depreciated `mysql_fetch_assoc/array,` hence I don't think that this is a duplicate question.

I have a MySQL table with 5 columns,

`ID | NAME | AGE | GENDER | HEIGHT`

If I want to store the values of `NAME, AGE, GENDER` in a PHP array,

```
$query=$mysqli->query("SELECT NAME,AGE,GENDER FROM TableName")
while($result = $query->fetch_assoc()
{
$array = [];
}
```

Will my array be stored in the format of 
`$array=[[Name,Age,Gender],[Name,Age,Gender]]`?

If not, what would be my approach in doing this?

Comment: Just try it yourself...

Comment: At least try first...

Comment: Actually I did, but as you can see my code is wrong, hence I am confirming my results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very simple. You just have to append the `result` variable in to main array. Like this,

```
$array =array();
while($result = $query->fetch_assoc()
{
$array[] = $result;
}
```

`$result` is an array ([fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) it returns result-set in array)  so just append that into main array to get the desired result.
 (`$array=[[Name,Age,Gender],[Name,Age,Gender]]`)

Comment: Looks good, however, calling $array[1][1] will result in a unidentified offset. 

Any ideas?

Comment: Access like this, `$array[1]["name"]`, `$array[1]["age"]` etc... Where first index get changed for each result through loop. E.g 0,1,2,3 etc...

Comment: It works. Thanks, tested with a json encode. Came out the results!

Comment: Not really sure why you got downvoted.. but oh well

Answer (score -1):

```
$data =[];
$i=0;
while($result = $query->fetch_assoc(){
  $data[$i][] = $result;
  $i++;
}
```